# HyperTerminal in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, hyperterminal

I recently purchased a laptop with [Windows 7 Home Premium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_7_editions#Main_editions), and it doesn't any in-built terminal, so I need to copy `hyperterminal.exe` from an external source and then execute it.

I am planning to upgrade to Windows 8. Does Windows 8 have the [HyperTerminal](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/app_terminal.mspx) program by default? If not, then do I need to install it from Windows Components or install it externally from Microsoft’s site?

Comment: _Hyper-terminal?_ If you're not connecting through dial-up might as well us PuTTY instead.

Comment: @r.tanner.f, that is an alternate option when no availablity of Hyper-Terminal, my first choice is Hyper-Terminal only.

Comment: What are you using it for? Personally, I use PuTTY or KiTTY.

Comment: Connecting to Modem, sometimes network device with IP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have [Windows 8 Pro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_8_editions#Editions), and I don't have the HyperTerminal program installed by default. Additionally, I don't see any option to install it via Windows feature install.

According to [this post about HyperTerminal in Windows 8](http://mikemstech.blogspot.com/2012/09/get-hyperterminal-in-windows-8-and.html), you'll have to copy it over from a previous installation of Windows XP or [Windows Server 2003](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_2003). If you have them from your Windows 7 machine, save them for Windows 8. Or you could use [one of the alternative terminal emulators](http://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-7/windows-7-hyperterminal/). I've used [TeraTerm](http://ttssh2.sourceforge.jp/) in the past, and it was pretty solid.